# WPF combobox dynamic binding

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpfdatagrid, dynamic-binding

I've a combo box with in data grid edititemtemplate and i write some code in combo box loaded event like:

**Code:**

```
private void cmbGFld_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender; 
            cmb.ItemsSource = FieldsList.GetFieldList();
            ConditionField cData = condLists[FieldGrid.SelectedIndex];
            cmb.SelectedItem = cData.FieldType;
        }
```

**XAML Code:**

```
<toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate x:Name="editTemplate">
                                            <ComboBox Loaded="cmbGFld_Loaded" BorderBrush="Transparent" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FieldType}" SelectedValuePath="Name" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="13" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="DimGray" x:Name="cmbGFld" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplate2}">
                                                <ComboBox.Resources>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}">Green</SolidColorBrush>
                                                </ComboBox.Resources>
                                                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                            </ComboBox>

                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

But the problem is when ever i try to edit the combo box it doesn't showing which is already selected, any one help me.

Thanks,
@nag.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without `cmb.SelectedItem = cData.FieldType;` in `cmbGFld_Loaded()`. This will overwrite the binding `SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FieldType}"` in your XAML. Set the selected item in the binded FieldType property instead. I don't know your application but something like:

```
FieldType = condLists[FieldGrid.SelectedIndex].FieldType;
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, i changed my code as above but when ever i call cmb.selecteditem= condlist[fieldgrid.selectedindex].fieldtype i'm getting null.